# How do I get two images to toggle on mouseover/mouseout?

Tags: jquery

I have a black box, and a red box. When I mouseover the black box, the black box disappears and the red box appears and when I mouseout over the newly appeared red box, the red box disappears and the black box re-appears. Then on the second cycle of repeating that, I get stuck on the red box and it doesn't toggle back to the black box. How can I fix this?

```js
$(function() {

  $('#black1').on('mouseover', function() {
   $('#black1').toggle();
  $('#red1').toggle();
  $('#red1').on('mouseout', function() {
   $('#red1').toggle();
  $('#black1').toggle();
  });
  });
 });
```

```css
div {width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    
}

#black1{
    background-color:black;
}
#red1{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red1" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="black1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using show(), hide() functions.

```
 $('#black1').on('mouseover', function() {
   $('#black1').hide();
   $('#red1').show();
});
 $('#red1').on('mouseout', function() {
   $('#red1').hide();
   $('#black1').show();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try to handle every `mouseover` alone see this :

```js
$(function() {
         // event listeners on mouseover of black1
  $('#black1').on('mouseover', function() {
   $('#black1').toggle();
  $('#red1').toggle();
      });
         // event listeners on mouseover of red1
  $('#red1').on('mouseout', function() {
   $('#red1').toggle();
  $('#black1').toggle();
  });

 });
```

```css
div {width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    
}

#black1{
    background-color:black;
}
#red1{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red1" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="black1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have manage when you mouseover on black box and after the red box. but you do not have the code for the red one in first and the black one in second.

You put the code to pass from red to black in the code for black to red.
idk if it's clear enough.